# jquery hide html data for image

Tags: jquery, html, image

I use

```
jQuery('.relatedproductdetailsdiv h5').html('');
```

and

```
jQuery('.relatedproductdetailsdiv .singlerel_shortdes').html('');
```

for hiding a `h5` and `singlerel_shortdes` contents under the `relatedproductdetailsdiv` div. Now I want to hide image content under the `relatedproductdetailsdiv` div

Comment: please show us `relatedproductdetailsdiv ` div code..

Comment: jQuery('.relatedproductdetailsdiv img').hide();

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.relatedproductdetailsdiv img').hide();
```

Will hide all `img` tags within your div with the class `relatedproductdetailsdiv`.

The images will be hidden, rather than the html within the tag removed (which is what your examples provided are doing), assuming that fits your needs.